# Using cvQueryFrame and boost::thread together

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, opencv

I need to call `cvQueryFrame` (to capture a frame from a webcam with opencv) instead a thread created with boost. Here is a little example code:

```
void testCVfunc(){
    IplImage* frame;
    CvCapture *capture;
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);
    if(!capture){
        exit(1);
    }
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    cvNamedWindow("testCV", 1);

    while(frame = cvQueryFrame(capture)){
        if(!frame){
            exit(2);
        }
        cvShowImage("testCV", frame);
        cvWaitKey(1);
    }
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}

int main(){
    //Method 1: without boost::thread, works fine
    testCVfunc();

    //Method 2: with boost::thread, show black screen
    char entree;
    boost::thread threadTestCV = boost::thread(&testCVfunc);
    std::cin >> entree;
}
```

As the comments say, `testCVfunc` does its job if I don't call it from a `boost::thread`, but I get a black screen if I use `boost::thread`.
I don't get the problem, maybe someone does?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen some problems when OpenCV is being executed from a secondary thread and it's difficult to pinpoint the origin of the problem when the behavior is not consistent on all platforms.

For instance, **your source code worked perfectly with OpenCV 2.3.0 on Mac OS X 10.7.2**. I don't know what platform you are using, but the fact that it worked on my computer indicates that OpenCV has some implementation issues with the platform you are using.

Now, if you can't move OpenCV's code to the primary thread, then you might want to start thinking about creating a 2nd program to handle all OpenCV related tasks, and use some sort of IPC mechanism to allow this program to communicate with your main application.

Comment: cvNamedWindow() is not the problem, and I'm specifically trying to run OpenCV from another thread, so your second suggestion is not really helping (my complete program use another library that has to be executed from a second thread). Thanks anyway, maybe another thought? Why openCV wouldnt take threading in charge?

Comment: What system is that? Win? Linux? Mac? What opencv version are you using?

Comment: sorry, forgot to say such basic information. I'm on Windows 7, using opencv 2.3.

Comment: Updated my answer. This is as far as I can go. Good luck. My suggestion of creating the window in the main thread came from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050369/display-image-in-second-thread-opencv). And this comment: *The only tricky thing is that OpenCV wants the “imshow”s to be on the main thread. This I learned empirically, form trial and error* , [came from here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/11/22/kinect-and-opencv-2-1/). People found several problems with OpenCV running on secondary threads on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by calling

```
cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);
```

in the main thread, even if it doesn't really answer the question:

> why is this not working? question.

Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling cv::startWindowThread(); in the main app and then creating a window within your thread. This worked for me.