# Using OpenCV, Boost threading and multiple cameras

Tags: c++, linux, boost, opencv

I am trying to write a program that is able to capture images from two different cameras in two different threads. I want to do this because when I do this in the same thread I have to keep waiting for cvQueryFrame twice the amount of time and so i can not grab images at 30 fps (I get 15 FPS from each camera).

I have taken a look at this SO post, but this only works for one camera. [Using cvQueryFrame and boost::thread together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364241/using-cvqueryframe-and-boostthread-together)

My current program gives varying results, sometimes it gives memory leaks, usually I just don't see anything happening and sometimes it worls for a few seconds but the the image freezes again. The strange thing is that earlier when I didn't call cvShowImage, but had my imageProcessing function do something useful I could see that I was getting real time results from both cameras. I assume this means that it is possible to make this work, but that I made a stupid mistake somewhere. My OS is LINUX and I am using OpenCV 2.4

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cv.h>
#include <ml.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "producer_consumer_queue.hpp"



//Camera settings
int cameraWidth = 1280;
int cameraHeight = 720;
int waitKeyValue = 5;
bool threads_should_exit = false;

CvCapture * capture;
CvCapture * capture2;

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void grabFrame(concurrent_queue<IplImage* > * frame_queue, int camNumber) {
    try {
        //Load first frames
        cout << "grabFrame: " << camNumber << " init with " << cameraWidth << " x " << cameraHeight << endl;

        IplImage* frame;
        if (camNumber == 0)frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (camNumber == 1)frame = cvQueryFrame(capture2);
        while (frame && !threads_should_exit) {
            if (camNumber == 0)frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
            if (camNumber == 1)frame = cvQueryFrame(capture2);
            IplImage* frame_copy = NULL;
            frame_copy = cvCloneImage(frame);

            if (camNumber == 0)cvShowImage("NE", frame);
            cout << "grabFrame: " << camNumber << " pushing back to queue" << endl;
            frame_queue->push(frame_copy);

            int k = cvWaitKey(waitKeyValue);

            if (k == 1048603 || k == 27 || k == '\r') {

                cout << "grabFrame: Process killed" << endl;
                //release memory
                threads_should_exit = true;
            }

        }
    } catch (const concurrent_queue<IplImage* >::Canceled & e) {
        cout << "grabFrame: Show thread is canceled" << endl;
        return;
    }

}

void processFrames(concurrent_queue<IplImage* > * frame_queue0, concurrent_queue<IplImage* > * frame_queue1) {
    try {
        do {
            cout << "processFrames: Processing two frames" << endl;
            IplImage* frm = NULL;
            frame_queue0->wait_and_pop(frm);
            IplImage * frm2 = NULL;
            frame_queue1->wait_and_pop(frm2);
            cvReleaseImage(&frm);
            cvReleaseImage(&frm2);
        } while (!threads_should_exit);
    } catch (const concurrent_queue<IplImage* >::Canceled & e) {
        cout << "processFrames: Processing thread is canceled" << endl;
        return;
    }
}

int main() {
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    capture2 = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, cameraWidth);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, cameraHeight);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture2, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, cameraWidth);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture2, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, cameraHeight);

    boost::thread_group frame_workers;
    boost::thread_group frame_workers2;
    concurrent_queue<IplImage* > frame_queue(&frame_workers);
    concurrent_queue<IplImage* > frame_queue2(&frame_workers2);

    boost::thread * query_thread = new boost::thread(processFrames, &frame_queue, &frame_queue2);
    boost::thread * cam0_thread = new boost::thread(grabFrame, &frame_queue, 0);
    usleep(10000);
    boost::thread * cam1_thread = new boost::thread(grabFrame, &frame_queue2, 1);

    frame_workers.add_thread(query_thread);
    frame_workers.add_thread(cam0_thread);

    frame_workers2.add_thread(query_thread);
    frame_workers2.add_thread(cam1_thread);
    while (true) {
        if (threads_should_exit) {
            cout << "Main: threads should be killed" << endl;
            while (!frame_queue.empty()) {
                usleep(10000);
            }
            frame_workers.remove_thread(query_thread);
            frame_workers2.remove_thread(query_thread);
            frame_workers.remove_thread(cam0_thread);
            frame_workers2.remove_thread(cam1_thread);

            frame_workers.join_all();
            break;
        }
        usleep(10000);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

EDIT:

I added a simple function to detect a piece of paper to see if everything is working fine when I don't call on `cvShowImage()`. My program can detect a piece of paper fine if I don't call `cvShowImage()`. If I do the program has strange behavior again and freezes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should only be one thread manipulating the GUI (this is true for just about any GUI framework). You should organize your code so that `cvShowImage` is only invoked from the main "GUI thread".

It seems that the work that's being done in `query_thread` could just as easily be done inside the main thread.

Comment: I adjusted my code as you suggested and moved the whole query_thread to the main thread, but this results in exactly the same behavior. If I don't call cvShowImage the program works fine.

Comment: I did, but I also needed to move cvWaitKey() to the main thread and limit my frame grabbing to 30 FPS. Thanks for your help!